# Manually (re)trigger ViewModel function after popping another Composable from the backstack

Tags: android, kotlin, mvvm, android-jetpack-compose, android-viewmodel

I have the following flow: When the app starts, a screen with popular items is displayed. User logs in, on successful login the backstack is popped and the user returns to the screen with the popular items. But when logged in, the items that the user liked/looked at last should also be displayed.

In non-Compose, I'd just retrigger the function in the viewModel that gets all items. But in Compose, I'd end up in an endless loop if I tried to call the function from the Composable.

My question is - how can I reload the items after the user returns from a successful login to the start screen? And what is best practice in such a case?

**ViewModel**

```
private val _itemsFlow = MutableStateFlow(emptyList())
val itemsFlow: StateFlow<List<Item>> = _itemsFlow

init {
   getItems()
}

private fun getItems() {
   viewModelScope.launch {
      itemRepository.getItems().collect { items ->
         _itemsFlow.value = items
      }
   }
}
```

**Composable**

```
@Composable
fun Home(viewModel: HomeViewModel = hiltViewModel()) {
   val items by viewModel.itemsFlow.collectAsState()
   ...
   // used later in a LazyRow
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out [side-effects](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/side-effects)

In your case something like this will help:

```
LaunchedEffect(Unit) {
    viewModel.getItems()
}
```

Comment: This is helpful, though I think actually popping from the nav graph is preferable with saveState=false.